# What's the tool that can wrap linux command line tool and provide additional function?

Tags: linux, sqlite, wrapper, read-eval-print-loop

For example, if we use `sqlite3`, we cannot use up arrow to view history(arrow keys will be translated to `^[[A` `^[[B` ...).

I remembered that there is a tool that can wrap it and provide this function,say it's 'xxx': `xxx sqlite3`. Then we can use arrow keys. I just forgot the xxx's name.

Answer (score 2):

Install `rlwrap` and run `rlwrap sqlite3`.

`deb` and `rpm` packges are available.